'Import' does not name a type, qml, qtcreator
Я получил несколько qml-файлов, добавил их к себе в проект. Создал заголовочный файл, в котором с помощью #include подключаю qml-файл. При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку: "'Import' does not name a type; did you mean '___'". Ошибка указывает на первую строку "import QtQuick 2.13".
Что я мог сделать неправильно, чтобы получить то, что имею?

Через include можно подключать только заголовочные файлы C++ или C. QML - это же другой язык программирования. Пример загрузки qml в с++: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdoc-demos-calqlatr-main-cpp.html
